# How to use same theme template for multiple taxonomy terms?

Tags: themes, template-hierarchy

How would I use the same template file for, say three specific taxonomy terms but not the remaining three?

I know `taxonomy-taxname.php` is the file for all terms

I know `taxonomy-taxname-termname.php` is the file for a specific term.

But let's say I want to have...

--`taxonomy-fruit-redfruit.php` for strawberries, tomatoes and raspberries

--`taxonomy-fruit-greenfruit.php` for watermelons, apples and kiwi

... *without* resorting to using duplicated individual theme files for each term?

Comment: Is the design of the templates for 6 the terms very different or is it just a matter of some content being different...?

Comment: A bit different. One group of three similar, another group of three similar - the two groups slightly different from each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You prepare templates (staying with your example):

- `content-redfruits.php`,
- `content-greenfruits.php`,
- `content-fruits.php`.

Then in taxonomy file `taxonomy-fruit.php` (copy and rename `taxonomy.php` or `index.php`), before main loop check the term slug of the currently-queried object.

```
$red_templ = ['strawberries', 'tomatoes', 'raspberries']; // term slugs
$green_templ = ['watermelons', 'apples', 'kiwi'];         // term slugs
$template = 'fruits';

$obj = get_queried_object();
if ( $obj instanceof WP_Term ){
    if ( in_array($obj->slug, $red_templ) )
        $template = 'redfruits';
    else if ( in_array($obj->slug, $green_templ) )
        $template = 'greenfruits';
}
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    get_template_part( 'content', $template );

endwhile;
```

### **Edit:**  (answer to the comment)

The above example can be written using `is_tax`:

```
$red_templ = ['strawberries', 'tomatoes', 'raspberries']; // term slugs
$green_templ = ['watermelons', 'apples', 'kiwi'];         // term slugs
$template = 'fruits';

if ( is_tax('fruit', $red_templ) )        // check taxonomy, then check terms
    $template = 'redfruits';
else if ( is_tax('fruit', $green_templ) ) // check taxonomy, then check terms
    $template = 'greenfruits';

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    get_template_part( 'content', $template );

endwhile;
```

`is_tax` performs some additional comparisons, but here is no significant difference in performance.
Each time you call `is_tax`, you check if given taxonomy matches the current one (this has already been checked when choosing a template file) and compare terms by id, slug and name.

You do not want to use `has_term` in this case. This function works on a post, therefore for empty terms it will return falsely `false`.

Comment: So, essentially, use a single taxonomy-fruits.php, and then conditionally change some of the content using one of several partial templates, based on which term was accessed? I assume content-fruits.php would be the default for all non-specified terms?

Comment: @RobertAndrews Exactly

Comment: @nmr, I was learning about doing the same as the original poster for different category pages that I have, so I am wondering why your code looks different than the examples on the codex with `is_tax()` and `has_term()` and so on. So just for clarification, please, is your answer an example application of [conditional tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) in a template file, or is it another approach? Edit: If it is different, which method is better and why?

Comment: @jsmod I edited the answer. I used `get_queried_object` because I don't like to check the same thing unnecessarily several times.